# MySQL ERROR 1111

Tags: mysql

Following this query I got ERROR 1111

```
SELECT estilista.estilo 
FROM   (SELECT distrito.n_distrito, 
               Count(*) AS cantidad 
        FROM   distrito, 
               establece_orden, 
               seguridad 
        WHERE  seguridad.id_cuerpo = establece_orden.cod_seguridad 
               AND distrito.n_distrito = establece_orden.n_distrito 
        GROUP  BY distrito.n_distrito) AS libres, 
       distrito, 
       estilista, 
       tributo 
WHERE  libres.n_distrito = tributo.n_distrito 
       AND tributo.cod_tributo = estilista.cod 
       AND libres.cantidad = ALL (SELECT Min(Count(*)) AS minimo 
                                  FROM   distrito, 
                                         establece_orden, 
                                         seguridad 
                                  WHERE  seguridad.id_cuerpo = 
                                         establece_orden.cod_seguridad 
                                         AND distrito.n_distrito = 
                                             establece_orden.n_distrito 
                                  GROUP  BY distrito.n_distrito);
```

Comment: what error you got ? show the whole error please

Comment: I guess `Min(Count(*))` this is generating the error in your subquery

Answer (score 0):

It's meaningless to use = ALL: how can a single libres.cantidad simultaneously be equal to more than one Min(Count(*)) ? ALL is only ever used with a comparison operator that can match more than one value, such as >= or <>: see [Subqueries with `ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/all-subqueries.html).

try this

```
  SELECT estilista.estilo 
   FROM   (SELECT distrito.n_distrito, 
           Count(*) AS cantidad 
    FROM   distrito, 
           establece_orden, 
           seguridad 
    WHERE  seguridad.id_cuerpo = establece_orden.cod_seguridad 
           AND distrito.n_distrito = establece_orden.n_distrito 
    GROUP  BY distrito.n_distrito) AS libres, 
   distrito, 
   estilista, 
   tributo 
  WHERE  libres.n_distrito = tributo.n_distrito 
   AND tributo.cod_tributo = estilista.cod 
   AND libres.cantidad in (SELECT Count(*) AS minimo 
                              FROM   distrito, 
                                     establece_orden, 
                                     seguridad 
                              WHERE  seguridad.id_cuerpo = 
                                     establece_orden.cod_seguridad 
                                     AND distrito.n_distrito = 
                                         establece_orden.n_distrito 
                              GROUP  BY distrito.n_distrito
                              ORDER BY minimo ASC LIMIT 1);
```